# Is there any way to convert pretrained model from PyTorch to ONNX?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, caffe2, onnx

I trained StarGAN model on my custom dataset.
And I need to convert this model from .pth(Pytorch) to .pb for using on Android studio.
I searched a lot and I found some ways for conversion. 
However all solutions don't work on my case.

I tried on small network that includes only one nn.Linear layer.
On this network, solutions work very well!

I think, my network includes Conv2D layer and MaxPooling2D layer so conversion processing doesn't work.

First, this is my network(StarGAN).

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np


class ResidualBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dim_in, dim_out):
        super(ResidualBlock, self).__init__()
        self.main = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(dim_in, dim_out, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.InstanceNorm2d(dim_out, affine=True, track_running_stats=True),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(dim_out, dim_out, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.InstanceNorm2d(dim_out, affine=True, track_running_stats=True))

    def forward(self, x):
        return x + self.main(x)


class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, conv_dim=64, c_dim=5, repeat_num=6):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()

        layers = []
        layers.append(nn.Conv2d(3 + c_dim, conv_dim, kernel_size=7, stride=1, padding=3, bias=False))
        layers.append(nn.InstanceNorm2d(conv_dim, affine=True, track_running_stats=True))
        layers.append(nn.ReLU(inplace=True))

        curr_dim = conv_dim
        for _ in range(2):
            layers.append(nn.Conv2d(curr_dim, curr_dim * 2, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False))
            layers.append(nn.InstanceNorm2d(curr_dim * 2, affine=True, track_running_stats=True))
            layers.append(nn.ReLU(inplace=True))
            curr_dim = curr_dim * 2

        for _ in range(repeat_num):
            layers.append(ResidualBlock(dim_in=curr_dim, dim_out=curr_dim))

        for _ in range(2):
            layers.append(nn.ConvTranspose2d(curr_dim, curr_dim // 2, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False))
            layers.append(nn.InstanceNorm2d(curr_dim // 2, affine=True, track_running_stats=True))
            layers.append(nn.ReLU(inplace=True))
            curr_dim = curr_dim // 2

        layers.append(nn.Conv2d(curr_dim, 3, kernel_size=7, stride=1, padding=3, bias=False))
        layers.append(nn.Tanh())
        self.main = nn.Sequential(*layers)

    def forward(self, x, c):
        c = c.view(c.size(0), c.size(1), 1, 1)
        c = c.repeat(1, 1, x.size(2), x.size(3))
        x = torch.cat([x, c], dim=1)
        return self.main(x)


class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, image_size=128, conv_dim=64, c_dim=5, repeat_num=6):
        super(Discriminator, self).__init__()
        layers = []
        layers.append(nn.Conv2d(3, conv_dim, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1))
        layers.append(nn.LeakyReLU(0.01))

        curr_dim = conv_dim
        for _ in range(1, repeat_num):
            layers.append(nn.Conv2d(curr_dim, curr_dim * 2, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1))
            layers.append(nn.LeakyReLU(0.01))
            curr_dim = curr_dim * 2

        kernel_size = int(image_size / np.power(2, repeat_num))
        self.main = nn.Sequential(*layers)
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(curr_dim, 1, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(curr_dim, c_dim, kernel_size=kernel_size, bias=False)

    def forward(self, x):
        h = self.main(x)
        out_src = self.conv1(h)
        out_cls = self.conv2(h)
        return out_src, out_cls.view(out_cls.size(0), out_cls.size(1))
```

And this is the error message.

```
TypeError: object of type 'torch._C.Value' has no len() (occurred when translating repeat)
```

Is there any way for conversion? Help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when trying to produce a graph of my model, using TensorboardX.

I believe the error comes from what operators `torch.onnx` currently supports. You can check this link:
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/onnx.html
Under section **Supported operators**, you will see that `repeat` is not listed.

To answer your question, it seems that you currently cannot convert a model using `repeat` with `torch.onnx`.